# Change variable if option is selected

Tags: jquery, html

So I got this selecter with an id of mySelect.

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>      
</select>
```

And if one of these options is selected I want to set the variable color in jquery to a value. And later use this color variable.

```
var color; 
    $('#mySelect option:selected').change(function(){ 

    if($(this).val() == '1') {
    color = #000080;    
    return color;
    }
    if($(this).val() == '2') {
    color = #ff0000;    
    return color;
    }
});
```

The jquery code is not correct and I can't seem to fix it..

Comment: what do you mean by one of these option. By default, first option is selected for dropdown.

Comment: well I'd like to extend it that when option 2 is selected another color is assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change event should be on the `select` element, not on `option:selected`, try this:

```
var color; 
$('#mySelect').change(function(){ 

    if($(this).val() == '1') {
        color = "#000080";//<- Needs to be a string  
        return color;
    }
});
```

Couple of things to note:

1. I have changed the selector to use the correct ID (`#mySelect`), though I assume that is a typo on your part?
2. You don't actually need to use `option:selected` for `value`, though you would need this is you wanted to access the selected `option` DOM element (e.g. to get the `text`)
3. I fixed your color string (see comments above)
4. Not sure why you are using a `return` statement, you should probably just remove this

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sJqFP/)

**Advanced Solution**

I would recommend that instead of using a set of if/else statements that you use an array to store your list of colours, you can then use the `val()` as the index (don't forget to subtract 1 as it is zero based). Like this:

```
var colors = ["#000080", "#008000", "#800000"];

var color;
$('#mySelect').change(function () {
    color = colors[$(this).val() - 1];
    return color;
});
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/sJqFP/1/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for the solution and the information provided. Great help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#categorie option:selected') // This is for selected option which won't work 
                                // change event handler
```

Change it back to select tag

```
$('#mySelect').change(..  //also change your id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var color; 
$('#mySelect').change(function(){ 

  switch($(this).val()) {
    case "1": color = "#000080";break;
    case "2": color = "#FF0080";break;
    case "3": color = "#EE0080";break;
  }
  alert(color);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pesulap/cMLmU/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

`$(function()
{ $('#mySelect').on('change',function(){ if($(this).val()==1) { /*do stuff here*/ } }); });`

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PwMxk/1/